# Similar to 'String.indexOf("text")' function in Swift

Tags: java, swift, string, indexof

I am new to Swift and I was looking for some help, please.

I have a String

```
let someString = "Here is an example of string"
```

I want to get `is an example` part of it.
In Java I can do something like:

```
String someString = "Here is an example of string"    
String s = someString.substring(someString.indexOf("is "), someString.indexOf(" of"));
```

I was wondering if there is anything similar in Swift to Java's 
`String.indexOf("some string")` in order to find an index of the element of String. I've looked around and couldn't find anything.
What I need it for is to find `startIndex` and `endIndexes` of a string that I am going to substring. I understand that it can be done easier with something like `string.endIndex.advanceBy(-9)`, but string I am looking to go through is a couple of paragraphs long.

**Found the solution: 
`NSString.range(of: "string").location` returns the index I've been looking for in case anyone wondering**

**UPDATE**

Leo's answer works as well for anyone looking for an alternative:

> Note that you should make sure to only search the range " of" string
>   after the occurrence to the "is ". `if let lower = someString.range(of: "is ")?.upperBound, let upper = someString.range(of: " of", range: lower..<someString.endIndex)?.lowerBound { let substring = someString[lower..<upper] // "an example" }`

Comment: if you need the substring between the two substrings you just need to get the proper lower and upper indexes `if let lower = someString.range(of: "is ")?.upperBound,
   let upper = someString.range(of: " of")?.lowerBound {
    let substring = someString[lower..<upper]    //  "an example"
}`

Comment: Note that you should make sure to only search the range " of" string after the occurrence to the "is ". `if let lower = someString.range(of: "is ")?.upperBound, let upper = someString.range(of: " of", range: lower..<someString.endIndex)?.lowerBound {
    let substring = someString[lower..<upper] // "an example"
}`

Comment: BTW `Range<String.Index>` has no location property and range it is not a String static method

Comment: Are you sure you have added the `import UIKit` or `import Foundation` to your file?

Comment: I've wrote String by accident, meant to write NSString.range(of: "").location.

Comment: Don't use NSString. Swift native type is String

Comment: By the way, thank you for the solution you provided, it works as well

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something like this with the `range` method of Swifts `String`. It will return the range of the given string within the search string.

In Swift the start and end index is the `lowerBound` and `upperBound` of the resulting `range`.

Here is an example based on your example:

```
import Foundation

let text = "Here is an example of string"

if let textRange = text.range(of: "is an example") {
    textRange.lowerBound // startIndex
    textRange.upperBound // endIndex
    let otherText = text.substring(with: textRange) // result = "is an example"

    print("\(otherText)")
}
```

You can put this in a Playground and play around with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem is that I know the string it starts with and the string it ends with but the text in between may be different. I might not have been clear. So for example string may be "Here is the example of string" I know that it starts with "is" and end at the beginning of "of" but string in between them could be anything, that why I am trying to find exact startIndex and endIndex